# Auth.signIn() issue: cannot read property 'username'

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm getting the error: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined when trying to sign in with a valid and confirmed user in Cognito. Even if i manually put the username and password in the Auth.signIn( , ) function, i still receive the same error.

I'm using iOS and React Native. I have also updated and done `react-native link amazon-cognito-identity-js` (version @3.0.15)

How can I log in?

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'

export default class SignIn extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    state = {
      username: ' ',  //this is set from a TextInput field
      password: ' '   //this is set from a TextInput field
    };
  }

// Sign in users with Auth
  async signIn() {
    const { username, password } = this.state
    await Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(user => {
      this.setState({ user })
      Alert.alert('Signed In Successful!')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error when signing in: ', err)
        Alert.alert('Error when signing in: ', err)
    })
  }
}


render() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
         <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={this.signIn}
            style={styles.button}>
            <Text> Sign In</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
)}

}
```

Comment: should that be `this.state = { ... etc}` in the constructor?

Comment: Yes i tried that first. Didn't have any effect

Comment: I'm surprised, also surprised with `manually put the username and password` getting the same error - where did you manually do this?

Answer (score 0):

first, state should be like this

```
this.state = {
      username: ' ',  //this is set from a TextInput field
      password: ' '   //this is set from a TextInput field
    };
```

there is an issue here.

```
this.setState({ user })
```

this code is equal to :

```
this.setState({ user:user })
```

which is not correct. Because there is no "user" property in the state. this function recognizes the properties of the state. it should be like this:

```
this.setState({ username:user })
```